# Angular is still not recognising $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I am injecting ngResource in my app's module :

```
angular.module('confusionApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource'])
```

, then injecting $resource dependency in my service :

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
    .constant('baseURL', 'http://localhost:3000/')
    .service('menuFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource, baseURL) {
```

I have also included the script in my index.html file :

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
```

I am running a json-server on my machine and whenever the $resource is requesting data, the browser's js console cannot identify $resource and shows this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- menuFactory

Please help or do point towards somewhere which can help!!

> Update

my bower.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
"font-awesome": "~4.4.0",
"angular": "1.4.x",
"angular-route": "1.4.x",
"angular-resource": "1.4.x",
"angular-ui-router": "~0.2.17"
}
```

Comment: Going to sound stupid but is the file actually installed?  Nothing is wrong with your code so check to make sure `../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js` is not 404ing in ur browser  .  If this was happening it would have died at the first line where u declared the dependancy.

Comment: Yes , exactly I thought this..... it would have 404ed this file first, then maybe showed me the error, but it's not...... I've checked.... I'm posting the bower.json if it helps...... as I've used bower.

Comment: one irrelevant question: why do you have a service, but you named it menuFactory? why not menuService?

Comment: Actually I defined it as a factory before....then changed it to service....just didn't change the name..... anyways... that was a good advice... I will make sure of that from next time @AbdulAhmad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a conflict between versions of angular and angular-resource. I don't know how it got installed, given I had installed it through bower, although I did explicitly mentioned it's version in bower.json, did not let the bower command tool save it while installing. 
I had to remove the angular-resource from the bower_components and also removed the dependency from bower.json and reinstall angular-resource with the -S flag.